# mongodb C# Driver update multiple fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a dictionary that I'd like to use to update a mongodb record. I'm using a simple foreach to iterate the dictionary and construct an UpdateDefinition object.
The problem is that I can't initialize an empty UpdateDefinition object, and therefore am forced into initializing the UpdateDefinition with an existing key value:

```
IDictionary<string, object> document = GetDocument();
string firstKey = document.Keys.First();
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set(firstKey, document[firstKey]);

foreach (var key in document.Keys)
{
    update = update.Set(key, document[key]);
}
```

This is horrible. FilterDefinition has an empty Filter which works great for this purpose. Is there anything similar for building iterative UpdateDefinitions?

Comment: I think a similar question has the right answer for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346654/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-how-to-use-updatedefinitionbuilder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using clues:

1. `BsonDocument` has a constructor with a `Dictionary` parameter
2. There's an implicit conversion from `BsonDocument` to `UpdateDefinition`
3. There's an implicit conversion from `BsonDocument` to `FilterDefinition`

you can do reduce everything to this one liner, (upsert not mandatory):

```
// IDictionary<string, object> dict = ...;
collection.UpdateOne(new BsonDocument("_id", "some_filter"), new BsonDocument("$set", new BsonDocument(dict)), new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```